# Dividing n stones into x piles of size greater than q but less than r

Tags: combinatorics

Perhaps this is a basic question, but I'm having a hard time figuring out a general form for the solution.

Consider a pile of indistinguishable stones of size **n**.  How many ways can the pile of **n** stones be divided into **x** piles of size greater than **q** but less than **r** if the order of the piles does not matter?  How does this answer change if the order of the piles does matter?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I believe this really is the same as asking "How many different ways can we split $n - (q+1)x$ stones into $x$ piles all of size less than $r - (q+1)$?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each pile is going to have more than $q$ stones, you might as well set aside $qx$ stones ahead of time in which to distribute $q$ to each pile; there is no choice involved in that procedure. The only choices left are how to distribute $n-qx$ stones to $x$ locations in which each pile has at least $1$ stone but less than $r-q$ stones. If the piles are ordered, respectively unordered, this amounts to counting [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), respectively [integer compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29), of $n-qx$ into $x$ parts each of size $<r-q$.

Using generating functions, these counts are given respectively by

$$[t^x w^{n-qx}]\left(\frac{w}{1-tw}\frac{w^2}{1-tw^2}\cdots\frac{w^{r-q-1}}{1-tw^{r-q-1}}\right), \qquad [w^{n-qx}]\left(\frac{w^{r-q}-w}{w-1}\right)^x.\quad$$

I doubt the first has a nice explicit form. Via Newton-Binomial expansion, the second is

$$(-1)^{n-(q+1)x}\sum_{t=0}^x (-1)^{(r-q)t}\binom{x}{t}\binom{-x}{n-(q+1)x-(r-q-1)t}.$$

Comment: Thank you!  This is an excellent answer.  What, though, are the w and t terms in the function referring to?  I read through the links you included in your post (which were very insightful and useful, I might add), but did not find any mention within them of what these variables might mean.

Comment: @BryceC. Look up "generating functions." The variables do not represent anything.